# Download whole video from AWS S3 at once. Currently cannot fast forward

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video

In my AWS S3 bucket, I have some screen recording videos, which have been captured by mediarecorder and uploaded. I want to embed the videos in a player on a different site.

at the moment my html video player looks like this:

```
<video width="100%" heigt="50%" controls *ngIf="videoLink">
   <source [src]="videoLink" type="video/webm" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

where videoLink = `https://{bucket}.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{video name}?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=XX%XXXX%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220126T090607Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=XX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject`

The problem is that when you click on play, the video is not fully available in the player. It seems to download in real time, and although you can rewind, you cannot fast forward past the latest bit to be downloaded. (So if you watch the video for 10 seconds, you can rewind and fastforward within those first 10 secs, but you can't go any further).

This is also the case when I download the video link from AWS directly and watch it in my browser.
Please can someone help me allow users to skip to any part of the video in the player like normal video players, where even if it hasnt loaded yet, it will start buffering from the point you skip to.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [CloudFront & AWS Elemental MediaConvert](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/) instead of using direct-S3 mp4 playback?

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm trying to implement that now

Comment: Let us know how it goes mate!